# How to query the Nth position in a json set in a jsonb column in posgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I need help with querying the first or second or any nth position in a JSON set.

```
create table myjson(jsondetails jsonb);

insert into myjson(jsondetails) values ('{"groups": "[group1,group2]"}');

select * from myjson;

select jsondetails->>'groups' from myjson;
```

I want to print just "group2".

I tried `select jsondetails#>> '{groups,1}'`. This results in an error.

Comment: Your `insert` is wrong.  The `groups` key contains the literal string `[group1,group2]` rather than what I suspect you want: `["group1","group2"]`.

Comment: See [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3bac6e836f20a01077629c3123bfad0e)

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching the site, I came across a posting "Query for array elements inside JSON type".

I realized the format that I entered the json set was incorrect. Fixing that helped me query the desired values.

insert into myjson(jsondetails) values ('{"groups": ["group1","group2"]}');

select * from myjson;

select jsondetails->'groups'->>1 from myjson;